# What is the proper way to clean up/destroy directives?

Tags: angularjs

Assuming I have multiple directives consisting of something like:

```
<mydirective id="1">...template content...</mydirective>
<mydirective id="2">...template content...</mydirective>
```

How do you go about destroying the directive? Usually I would do something in jquery where I `$('#2').remove();`

Aside from removing the specific directive from the dom, is there something else that has to be done, or some other way to destroy the dom element so you do not leave anything other "garbage" lingering? (i.e. orphan controllers, etc.)

Comment: Why would you want to destroy it?

Comment: As far as I know you generally don't need to clean up anything, only in some special situations. Make sure your application design is right, trying to remove directives and controllers on your own sounds wrong somehow.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that you would want to clean up would be parent scope listeners (eg. $rootScope) take a look at http://paulsalaets.com/posts/cleaning-up-angular-rootscope-event-listeners

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to do any cleanup work in a directive you can subscribe to the $destroy event.

In your link function:

```
element.on('$destroy', function() {
    // Do cleanup work
});
```